# Show that $C_{c}\cap \left\{ z=0\right\} =\partial B$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

Let $d_{0}>0$, $R>0$ and $p_{3}\in \left( 0,d_{0}\right) $ given. Consider  $C_{c}$ a any catenoid of radius $c>0$
centered $p=\left( 0,0,p_{3}\right)$  in $%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{3}$. Let $B$ a closed ball in the $z=0$ plane centered on the origin of
radius $R$.

Show that there $c\in \left[ 0,R\right]
$ such that $C_{c}$ is centered in $p=\left( 0,0,p_{3}\right) $ and

> > $$%
> > C_{c}\cap \left\{ z=0\right\} =\partial B$$

The problem is very intuitive. I tried to use the equation that describes
the points of a catenoid, but I could not solve the problem, $%
R=c\cosh\left( \frac{p_{3}}{c}\right) $.

Comment: I don't understand where this equation comes from. I expected to see something like $c\cosh(1/c) = R$, which only has solutions for $R\ge R_0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin you're right. I edited.

Comment: So there is a critical value $R_0 \approx 1.509$ below which there is no solution when $p_3=1$. Try a graphing calculator or something fancier. :) But $p_3$ will rescale this value somewhat.

Comment: @TedShifrin Can not you write it analytically?

Comment: Not in any closed form of which I am aware!